# How do I add different variables that are present in different classes using .map()/.filters()

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, option-type

I have three different type of fee (cost, deliveryServiceFee and fee)  in different objects and I want to add them up and put them in a variable called "totalDeliveryFee".

Here are the classes:

CartEntry.java

```java
package core.aggreagte

public class CartEntry {
@NotNull
@Valid
private Fulfillment fulfillment;

@DecimalMin("0.0")
private BigDecimal totalDeliveryFee;
}
```

Fulfillment.java

```java
package core.aggreagte

public class Fulfillment {
@Valid
private StoreDelivery storeDelivery;
}
```

StoreDelivery.java

```java
package core.aggreagte

public class StoreDelivery {

@DecimalMin("0.0")
private BigDecimal cost;

@DecimalMin("0.0")
private BigDecimal deliveryServiceFee;

private DeliveryWindow deliveryWindow;
}
```

DeliveryWindow.java

```java
package core.aggreagte

public class DeliveryWindow {
@DecimalMin("0.0")
private BigDecimal fee;
}
```

Summation of all three variables happens here in Calculator.java
Here is what I've got so far:

CartEntryTotalDeliveryFeeCalculator.java

```java
package core.calculator.cartEntry.impl;

import core.aggregate.CartEntry;
import core.aggregate.Fullfillment;
import core.aggregate.StoreDelivery;
import core.calculator.cartEntry.CartEntryCalculator

public class CartEntryTotalDeliveryFeeCalculator implements CartEntryCalculator{
@Override
public void calculate(final CartEntry cartEntry {
          Optional.of(cartEntry).filter(fulfillment -> Objects.nonNull(fulfillment.getFulfillment())).map(CartEntry::getFulfillment)
            .filter(storeDelivery -> Objects.nonNull(storeDelivery.getStoreDelivery()))
            .map(Fulfillment::getStoreDelivery).filter(deliveryFee -> Objects.nonNull(deliveryFee.getCost()))
            .filter(serviceFee -> Objects.nonNull(serviceFee.getDeliveryServiceFee()))
            .map(StoreDelivery::getDeliveryWindow).filter(windowFee -> Objects.nonNull(windowFee.getFee()));
}
}
```

Comment: How are they grouped? How many items are we talking about? You are leaving too many details.

Comment: Maybe add interface above your classes with method which will be used for calculations

Comment: Please don't create new accounts just to ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74320369/i-am-trying-to-add-three-different-value-from-different-classes-and-objects-to) with little to no improvement.

Comment: HI @hfontanez CartEntry, Fulfillment, StoreDelivery and DeliveryWindow are under same package which are imported into CartEntryTotalDeliveryFeeCalculator.java for calculations

Comment: @Manu, let me know if my answer is helpful or if it totally answered your question.

Comment: Hi @hfontanez
We cannot modify any of the classes (Fulfillment, CartEntry, StoreDelivery, DeliveryWindow). We need to fetch each of these values(cost, deliveryServiceFee and fee) from CartEntryTotalDeliveryFeeCalculator.java using Lambda functions and add to totalDeliveryFee variable present in CartEntry.java.
I hope this helps. I would really appreciate if you can tell me whether you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot modify these classes, you will need to rely on each of the getter methods of these classes. And, since all of the needed values are components and subcomponents of the `CartEntry` class, all you need is create a stream of all the fulfillments and use the getter methods to accumulate the sum of each of these values.

```
List<CartEntry> entries = List.of(new CartEntry(), new CartEntry());
        
double total =
    entries.stream()
        .mapToDouble(entry -> entry.getTotalDeliveryFee()
            .add(entry.getFulfillment().getStoreDelivery().getCost()
                .add(entry.getFulfillment().getStoreDelivery()
                        .getDeliveryServiceFee().add(entry.getFulfillment()
                        .getStoreDelivery().getDeliveryWindow().getFee())))
            .doubleValue())
        .sum();
```

That gathers all the totals from components and subcomponents of the `CartEntry` class.

One last observation: Since the classes are using annotations to guarantee "not null" objects and for decimal values to have a minimum value of 0.0, my assumption is that the use of `Optional` is really not needed. All subcomponents of `CartEntry` appear to be automatically created with a value of 0.0. If that assumption is correct, the above function should work perfectly as is. If the assumption is incorrect, then it will be required to  use `Optional.of()` and then return 0.0 for null decimal values.

Comment: Hi 
We cannot modify any of the classes (Fulfillment, CartEntry, StoreDelivery, DeliveryWindow).
We need to fetch each of these values(cost, deliveryServiceFee and fee) from CartEntryTotalDeliveryFeeCalculator.java using Lambda functions and add to totalDeliveryFee variable present in CartEntry.java

Comment: @Manu Since your fields are private, I assume they have getter methods. You should be able to extract the functionality from what I am doing inside the `getTotal` method. I will edit this solution to show you.

Comment: Yes, you are right all these fields have getter and setter methods

Comment: @Manu I did add a last minute note. Good luck on your project.

Comment: Hi @hfontanez We do need to check for each object and value to make sure they are not null. Something like what I did in CartEntryTotalDeliveryFeeCalculator.java I tried doing but I am getting errors from my side while debugging (NullPointer) 
Please would you be able to help me out regarding this. Thank you

Comment: @manu You have to prevent methods and data providers from returning null. Otherwise, you will have to check for null everywhere in your code. You can see why that is problematic.

Comment: @Manu For example, if your cart is empty, instead of returning a null list, your method should return an empty `List<CartEntry>`. This way, you should be able to sum the total of entries in the cart, which should be zero since the cart is empty. Of course, for this to work the `@DecimalMin("0.0")` has to work the way I think it should, which is to automatically initialize those variables to the min value.

Comment: @Manu In fact, I would argue that in cases where you would end up with a `null` cart instead of an empty cart, you would be better off throwing a an exception than returning `null`.